# Spring Security: I can save data despite the session is timed out

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I have a problem with Spring Security. It looks like this:

1. I change some data in a formular
2. I leave the computer for some time (enough to timeout the active session)
3. I come back to the computer
4. I click a "save" button in the webapp

Now - the data IS saved to the database, and then the app logs me out telling that my session has timed out. This behavior is improper, how to make sure that I am completely logged out after defined or default time, without any possibility to save data after the timeout?

My security-context.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <import resource="spring-database.xml" />

    <security:http pattern="/login" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/loginfailed" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/403" security="none" />

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login" />
        <security:access-denied-handler
            error-page="/403" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username= ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username,role from user_roles where username= ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an xml attribute in your `<security:logout` tag. Just add `invalidate-session="true"` in this tag. Through this way in every case of an invalid Session the user will be forced to re-login. You may read more information about this feature of Spring Secutity in [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/115642-invalidate-user-session-and-force-re-logging) thread.

Below you may find a part of your XML which includes the aforementioned attribute.

```
...

<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login" invalidate-session="true"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler
            error-page="/403" />
</security:http>

...
```